# Silverstripe Tests from Terminal

Tags: testing, silverstripe

How can i run only my tests in mysite instead of all the module & framework tests that silverstripe comes with?

when i run

```
 phpunit mysite/tests/PageTest
```

silverstripe runs all of the framework tests.

I can access my tests /dev/tests/PageTest  but not via the command line

I have a phpunit.xml file set up:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="framework/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true">

        <testsuite name="Default">
                <directory>mysite/tests</directory>
         </testsuite>

        <listeners>
                <listener class="SS_TestListener" file="framework/dev/TestListener.php" />
        </listeners>

        <groups>
                <exclude>
                        <group>sanitychecks</group>
                </exclude>
        </groups>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run tests according to [documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/testing/#via-the-sake-wrapper-on-command-line):

```
# Run specific tests (comma-separated)
sake dev/tests/FolderTest,OtherTest

# Skip some tests
sake dev/tests/all SkipTests=MySkippedTest
```

Comment: Thanks lev. Thats working! The docs included using phpunit command directly but i guess thats the good thing about there being more than one way to do it. : )

Answer (score 1):

You can also run tests by module. sake dev/tests/module/mysite to run all the tests in the my site folder.